# From marginal distribution to joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-verification

Consider two sequences of real-valued random variables, $\{X_n\}_n$ and $\{T_n\}_n$. Let $\rightarrow_d$ denote convergence in distribution. Assume

(1) $X_n\rightarrow_d L$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, where $L$ is a random variable

(2) $T_n\rightarrow_d \Delta$  as $n\rightarrow \infty$, where $\Delta\sim N(0,1)$

**Statement**: there exists a subsequence $\{ X_{n_j}, T_{n_j}\}_j$ such that $(X_{n_j}, T_{n_j})\rightarrow_d(L,\Delta)$ as $j\rightarrow \infty$, where $S$ is a a random variable.

[the statement is used in the proof of Theorem 7.10 page 98 of van der Vaart "Asymptotic Statistics"]

**Question**: could you help me to show the statement?

**Attempt**: I understand that

(i) (1) implies $X_n=O_P(1)$

(ii) (2) implies $T_n=O_P(1)$

(iii) (i)+(ii) implies $(T_n,X_n)=O_P(1)$

(iv) (iii) implies that there exists a subsequence $\{ X_{n_j}, T_{n_j}\}_j$ such that $(X_{n_j}, T_{n_j})\rightarrow_d(S,M)$ as $j\rightarrow \infty$, where $M$ is a a random variable (Prohorov's Theorem).

(v) Hence, $S\sim L$ and $M\sim \Delta$

(vi) Why $(S,M)\sim (L,\Delta)$?

Comment: Because if $(X_{n_j}, T_{n_j})\rightarrow_d(S,M)$ then $T_{n_j}\rightarrow_dM$ and if $T_{n}\rightarrow_d\Delta$ then $T_{n_j}\rightarrow_d\Delta$, hence $M=_d\Delta$.

Comment: But $(S,M)$ is not necessarily distributed as $(S,\Delta)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:** $T_n=\Delta$ for all $n$, $X_n=(-1)^n\Delta$ for all $n$. The joint distribution of the pair $(X_n,T_n)$ is that of $(\Delta,\Delta)$ for even $n$ but that of $(-\Delta,\Delta)$ for odd $n$. This illustrates the possibility that the limit distribution (along a subsequence) of the pair may depend on the subsequence.

Comment: Thanks. How can I apply your example to answer my question?

Comment: I guess the point is that while $S$ and $L$ must have the same distribution, as must $M$ and $\Delta$, the **Statement** does not make sense until you specify the joint distribution of $L$ and $\Delta$.